# Using Merge on a column and Index in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, merge

I have two separate dataframes that share a project number. In `type_df`, the project number is the index. In `time_df`, the project number is a column. I would like to count the number of rows in `type_df` that have a `Project Type` of `2`. I am trying to do this with `pandas.merge()`. It works great when using both columns, but not indices. I'm not sure how to reference the index and if `merge` is even the right way to do this.

```
import pandas as pd
type_df = pd.DataFrame(data = [['Type 1'], ['Type 2']], 
                       columns=['Project Type'], 
                       index=['Project2', 'Project1'])
time_df = pd.DataFrame(data = [['Project1', 13], ['Project1', 12], 
                               ['Project2', 41]], 
                       columns=['Project', 'Time'])
merged = pd.merge(time_df,type_df, on=[index,'Project'])
print merged[merged['Project Type'] == 'Type 2']['Project Type'].count()
```

Error:

> Name 'Index' is not defined.

Desired Output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

If you want to use an index in your merge you have to specify `left_index=True` or `right_index=True`, and then use `left_on` or `right_on`. For you it should look something like this:

```
merged = pd.merge(type_df, time_df, left_index=True, right_on='Project')
```

Answer (score 15):

Another solution is use [`DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df3 = type_df.join(time_df, on='Project')
```

For version `pandas 0.23.0+` [the `on`, `left_on`, and `right_on` parameters may now refer to either column names or index level names](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html):

```
left_index = pd.Index(['K0', 'K0', 'K1', 'K2'], name='key1')
left = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                     'key2': ['K0', 'K1', 'K0', 'K1']},
                    index=left_index)
                    
right_index = pd.Index(['K0', 'K1', 'K2', 'K2'], name='key1')

right = pd.DataFrame({'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                     'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3'],
                     'key2': ['K0', 'K0', 'K0', 'K1']},
                      index=right_index)
          
print (left)    
       A   B key2
key1             
K0    A0  B0   K0
K0    A1  B1   K1
K1    A2  B2   K0
K2    A3  B3   K1
        
print (right)
       C   D key2
key1             
K0    C0  D0   K0
K1    C1  D1   K0
K2    C2  D2   K0
K2    C3  D3   K1
```

---

```
df = left.merge(right, on=['key1', 'key2'])
print (df)
       A   B key2   C   D
key1                     
K0    A0  B0   K0  C0  D0
K1    A2  B2   K0  C1  D1
K2    A3  B3   K1  C3  D3
```

Comment: Can I pass numeric index of column instead of column name? I have duplicate column names and this one fails because of that.

Comment: Confusing. Current version of join does not have left_on and right_on.

Answer (score 3):

You must have the same column in each dataframe to merge on.

In this case, just make a 'Project' column for `type_df`, then merge on that:

```
type_df['Project'] = type_df.index.values
merged = pd.merge(time_df,type_df, on='Project', how='inner')
merged
#    Project  Time Project Type
#0  Project1    13       Type 2
#1  Project1    12       Type 2
#2  Project2    41       Type 1

print merged[merged['Project Type'] == 'Type 2']['Project Type'].count()
2
```