# python pandas - merge using key from df2 / index of df1

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have these two dataframes:

**avg_rating**

```
movieId      rating
  1         3.921240
  2         3.211977
  3         3.151040
  4         2.861393
  5         3.064592
```

**data**

```
         movieId      title                                 year
  0           1       Toy Story (1995)                      1995
  1           2       Jumanji (1995)                        1995
  2           3       Grumpier Old Men (1995)               1995
  3           4       Waiting to Exhale (1995)              1995
  4           5       Father of the Bride Part II (1995)    1995
```

I would like to merge them based on **movieId**. My issue is that in the first dataframe, the index is the movieId, while in the second dataframe the movieId is a value. 
How can I get around this? 
I just started learning pandas so excuse me if my question is stupid or badly written.

Comment: Please see the documentation for merge ... it's very clearly spelled out there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Merge on a column and Index in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528819/using-merge-on-a-column-and-index-in-pandas)

Comment: @Ajean - I try no answering clearly dupes, but sometimes it happens :(

Comment: @jezrael All good, I probably just rolled out on the wrong side of the bed today.  There may be a nicer-looking dupe than the one I chose, also, I just picked the first one that showed up.