# Merge two DataFrames based on containing string without iterator

Tags: python, pandas

I have two csv files imported as dataframes `A` and `C`. I want to match the strings of column `content` with the entry in `data.data` that contains the string from `A`.

```
A  time_a content    C  time_c data.data
   100    f00           400    otherf00other
   101    ba7           402    onlyrandom
   102    4242          407    otherba7other
                        409    other4242other

Should become:
time_a time_c content
100    400    f00
101    407    ba7
102    409    4242
```

My solution below uses iterators. But it works too slow. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/17834402) explains why and gives methods how to improve. But I struggle to implement any.

How can I do this with the optimized methods from pandas?

```
# reset_index() on both df
df_alsa_copy = df_alsa.copy() # Never modify your iterator
df_alsa_copy['cap_fno'] = -1

for aIndex, aRow in df_alsa.iterrows():
    for cIndex, cRow in df_c.iterrows():
        if str(aRow['content']) in str(cRow['data.data']):
            df_alsa_copy.loc[aIndex, 'cap_fno'] = df_c.loc[cIndex, 'frame.number']
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528819/using-merge-on-a-column-and-index-in-pandas
# Merge on frame.number column (bc I chose it to be included in alsa_copy as a column)
df_ltnc = pd.merge(df_alsa_copy, df_c, left_on='cap_fno', right_on='frame.number')
```

##### Also tried:

- Would work, if there is an exact match: [Pandas: Join dataframe with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44080248/pandas-join-dataframe-with-condition).
- I also managed to match my second frame against a known string with `series.str.contains`.
- The problem is, I fail to enter a dataframe column to match in `merge on=`. I can only enter a known string.
- The same problem arose, when I used `apply`.
- I did not succeed with `isin` or similar.

##### More info:

`A` holds timestamped content I fed into the program. `C` is a network capture. I want to know the time in between feeding and capture. I assume:

- The string occur in the same order in `A` and `C`.
- But in `C` there might be lines in between.
- Strings represent hex values.
- `data.data` contains other chars as well as the string I look for.
- Maybe I lack the pandas vocabulary, to look for the correct method.

Comment: Nvm, Had no louck on google. But I found a solution which is a bit faster through SO related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54768170/17834402. Not sure if it is seriously that hard to find or if it was just bad luck. Any advise: Delete this question or leave as duplicate, so others can find the original faster?

Comment: Which of the approaches from the link are  you referring to?

Comment: The new one with apply, bfill, lambda expression etc. Unfortunately, I do not fully understand how it works

Comment: I can provide an alternative solution without lambda and apply specifically to your use-case

Comment: if it is preformant, happy to see it. I could compare performance of both solutions then

Comment: I post an answer in a moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach using [`pandas.unique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.unique.html), [`pandas.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```py
unique_str = A['content'].unique()
matching_rows = C[C['data.data'].str.contains('|'.join(unique_str))]

out = pd.merge(matching_rows, A, left_on=matching_rows['data.data']
               .str.extract(f'({"|".join(unique_str)})')[0],
                right_on='content')[['time_a', 'time_c', 'content']]
print(out)
```

---

```
   time_a  time_c content
0     100     400     f00
1     101     407     ba7
2     102     409    4242
```

Comment: Works on the sample data provided. Still issues with my real data. Will report on perfomance, once sorted out.

Comment: This approach is expected to be more efficient but because I don't know the structure of your real data it because almost impossible to help you resolve those issues.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I figured it out. TLDR: My data has a problem, not the answer. LONG:  You answered, what I asked for. Your answer (correctly) assumes that 'unique_str' does not occur in mmulitple rows in C. However, in my data it does. My other coding approach just took the first appearance of the unique_str, which made it look correct. But your code actually gets the correct result and showed a flaw in my data.

Comment: Good to know that @PaulSmith

Answer (score 1):

if you want to improve speed, a different option you might consider is using Polars (https://www.pola.rs/). You can install Polars with `pip install polars`

The solution is the same to what @Jamiu proposes, I think he has the right approach. The only difference is Polars instead of Pandas.

I tested the 2 solutions by multiplying the number of rows by 1000. The Pandas solution takes 400ms while the Polars one takes 92ms.

```
import polars as pl

# convert the data to Polars dataframes
a, c = pl.from_pandas(A), pl.from_pandas(C)

# calculate unique values and join
unique_values = f"({a['content'].unique().str.concat('|').item()})"
out = (
    a
    .join(c.filter(pl.col('data.data').str.contains(unique_values)), 
    left_on = 'content', right_on = pl.col('data.data').str.extract(unique_values))
)

# convert back to Pandas if needed
out_pandas = out.to_pandas()
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will keep it in mind, when I need more performance. Right now, speed is okay. Jamiu helped get rid of the iterator. That increased performance by some orders of mangitude already.